# Are all exergonic reactions spontaneous?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Exergonic reactions have a negative $\Delta G$: the system loses free energy. Spontaneous reactions are also defined in the same way, as far as I know. Does this mean the two are synonymous?

There are some questions (e.g. [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/127674/87020)) asking the same question for exothermic reactions, but not all exergonic reactions are exothermic.

Comment: That depends on conditions under which your process is taking place. If process happening under constant temperature and pressure, then negative $\Delta$G  < 0 $\equiv$  spontaneous. Elif happening under constant entropy and pressure, $\Delta$H  < 0 $\equiv$  spontaneous